# How to replace a word in Python without replacing other forms of the word?

Tags: python

I am supposed to change a specific word in a string without changing the other forms of it.

For example, if the sentence is 
“The letters in your letter are great"

and I'm supposed to replace "letter" with "book",

The output should be 
"The letters in your book are great"
instead of
"The books in your book are great".

Can anyone please help me?

Sorry I'm new to coding and I'm really struggling.

Thank you so much!

(BTW this is just an example... and the code is supposed to work with any sentence with the specific word and other forms of the word, but all I need to change is the original not anything else.

Also the sentence is supposed to be an input so it's uncertain... But the word to be replaced is certain.)

Comment: By "forms of the word" do you mean homonyms? Or just anything that isn't exactly that word?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Is it only the difference plural 'letters' (='letters') vs. singular 'letter' (='book')? Or do you need to look into [WordNet Synonyms](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)?

Comment: "the other forms" just means anything that's not exactly that word, like past tense, etc. Sorry I know I'm really bad at this but that sentence is just an example, not the exact problem I have to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may split the string into words, replace the required word and then join the final words to a string:

```
def replace_word(text, findWord, replaceWord):
    return ' '.join(replaceWord if word == findWord else word for word in text.split(' '))
```

Then:

```
replace_word("This letters in your letter are great", "letter", "book")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping :)

Comment: Beware of punctuation, though. `replace_word("This letters in your letter are great!", "great", "awesome")` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

No of ways

One is (which you used):-

```
“The letters in your letter are great".replace(" letter ", " book ")
```

Other is regx

Comment: What if word to be replaced, *letter* in this case, comes at beginning or end of string?

Comment: @niyasc yes its fails but this solution is for predefined statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering... But this is just an example and there could be multiple forms of that words, but I can only change the original one with other forms also existing in this sentence.

Comment: Also the word could appear at the beginning or the end of the sentence.